# summation of total hours of an attribute (timestamp without time zone) using postgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, microsoft-powerbi

I wrote the following SQL query while I was trying to sum up the following column, but I had errors and it is not executing.. any ideas ..

```
SELECT
NUMTODSINTERVAL(SUM((TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(sensor.datedahour,1,2))*3600)+(TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(sensor.datedahour,4,2))*60)+TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(sensor.datedahour,7,2))), 'second')
FROM SENSORMINING.ra_fact_5min As sensor
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `substr`, you need to use `extract` or `date_part` with the timestamp and the name of field to extract, such as 'hour' or 'day'.

Calling `to_number` on the results is not necessary since these functions produce numbers, not strings.

See the doc at 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT